# High average load + low cpu usage + low disk usage + normal network usage + normal memory usage = ok or not?

Tags: performance, linux-networking, cpu-usage, high-load, load-average

I see high CPU average load several times a day on my server. For example, 21:20 and 22:45 on the following figure:

[image]

However, my CPU, disk, and network are all OK:

1. Disk

[image]

2. Network

[image]

3. CPU

[image]

[image]

4. Memory

[image]

5. Also do not see strange forks

[image]

[image]

6. Interrupts also ok

[image]

I have read through many posts like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/365061/high-load-average-low-cpu-usage-why/524818), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116849/why-load-is-high-despite-the-fact-that-neither-cpu-or-disk-is-overused) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134381/very-high-cpu-load-but-nothing-significant-in-top). But they mostly talk about some issues in network or disk, and my network & disk seems OK.

So what should I do? Or, is this even NOT a problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: The average load in modern Linux does not necessarily signal an issue. If the workload of that machine is unaffected there should be nothing to worry about even when load is reported high. Consider what are your service expectations for your app in that machine and if they are being affected or not.

Comment: @miguelbernadi Thank you!